# PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2 одна библиотека на все проекты

Tags: python, pycharm, библиотеки, lib, настройки

[image: настройки]
Как-то можно установить путь к папке куда будут скачиваться библиотеки и чтобы каждый проект брал библиотеку из этой папки.
Каждый раз создаю проект и в его директории появляется папка venv куда скачиваются нужные мне библиотеки. Я хочу указать для всех своих проектов какую-нибудь одну папку куда будут скачиваться новые библиотеки, чтобы не занимать лишнее место на диске и не скачивать каждый раз одни и те же библиотеки для нового проекта.
Среда разработки PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2.

Comment: Где-то в отдельной папке создайте вручную создайте общее виртуальное окружение (командой `python -m venv .venv`), туда установите нужные зависимости. Потом интерпретатор из этого виртуального окружения выбираете в своих проектах. Желательно, чтобы проекты были более-менее однотипные, чтобы не было 100500 разных зависимостей в одном виртуальном окружении, иначе PyCharm будет постоянно уходить в длительное их индексирование. По этой же причине не рекомендую использовать глобальный интерпретатор в проектах на PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве интерпретатора для своих проектов укажите "глобальный" интерпретатор. Выбор осуществляется в том меню, что вы открыли на скриншоте - кнопка `Add Interpreter`. После нажатия на кнопку появится меню, в котором необходимо выбрать вкладку `System Interpreter` и указать путь к интерпретатору. Путь к "глобальному" интерпретатору у вас будет примерно следующий:

`C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312`.

Вообще, виртуальное окружение позволяет использовать различные версии пакетов и зависимостей для каждого проекта, изолируя их друг от друга и предотвращая конфликты и несовместимости. Использование же глобального окружения - не очень хорошая практика.

Comment: По моему опыту - при использовании глобального интерпретатора PyCharm будет очень надолго уходить в индексацию установленных пакетов. Это просто максимально неудобно, на практике перекрывает все остальные доводы и хорошие практики.